# Upcase only the 3 and 4 letter words

Tags: regular-expression, search-replace

I've written a script to convert 3 and 4 characters words, since they often are abreviations in the texts I work on.
Here is the starting text :
`Diabetes - Hbp - Copd -` 
I want to transform it to :
`Diabetes - HBP - COPD -` 
My script is composed of two lines:

`%s/\v<(\w)(\w)(\w) /\u\1\u\2\u\3/g`

`%s/\v<(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w) /\u\1\u\2\u\3\u\4/g`

Which is working, but I guess there is a more elegant solution.
How to make vim  match and upcase only n to m characters words?

`:%s/\<\w\{3,4}\>` matches 3 or 4 characters words, but I can't find how to upcase my selection ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would propose:

```
:%s/\<\w\{3,4}\>/\U\0/g
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the fast and accurate answer. I just found the whole match operator ```\0``` and tried  ```:%s/\<\w\{3,4}\>/\u\0/g``` but it only makes the first letter of the word uppercase ...

Comment: Your are welcome :-) you have also the `\l` and `\L` operators and as an alternative for `\0` you have `&`.